# Given a singly linked list, group all odd nodes together followed by the even nodes

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, linked-list

I've been given this problem:

> Given a singly linked list, group all odd nodes together followed by the even nodes. Please note here we are talking about the node number and not the value in the nodes.
>
> You should try to do it in place. The program should run in O(1) space complexity and O(nodes) time complexity.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Given 1->2->3->4->5->NULL,
> return 1->3->5->2->4->NULL.
> ```

I have seen the solution but I don't understand it, I need someone to visually explain the solution to the problem.

This is a solution but it's in Java. I can't visualize pointer manipulations, can someone draw for me what is going around?

```
public ListNode oddEvenList(ListNode head) {
        if(head == null || head.next == null)
            return head;
        ListNode odd = head;
        ListNode even = head.next;
        ListNode evenHead = even;
        while(odd.next != null && even.next != null){
            odd.next = even.next;
            odd = odd.next;
            even.next = odd.next;
            even = even.next;
        }
        odd.next = evenHead;
        return head;
    }
```

Comment: It is difficult to see what is your problem with this simple programming assignment. Be more specific what your difficulties are.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I couldn't understand pointer manipulations, I need to see visually how they are constructed to understand them.

Comment: Then you need to first learn what are pointers and how those are manipulated?

Comment: I know what are pointers, but the assignment of the solution is confusing me, there are  a lot of pointer assignments, but I can't visualize them on paper, how they are used

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already got nice and detailed answers, so I feel a little bit stupid posting this, but it takes me sometime to made the drawings, so here it is anyway.

I'm going to explain the algorithm you posted, since it can be directly translated in C++ (I previously though that the "oddity" of a node was determined by its value not its position, and that would have required to modify the head with pointers to pointers).

I'm only going to visually explain this algorithm, I won't make a long digression on how this is actually just a "compressed" way of having two linked lists (one for odd elements and for even elements) and how to handle pointers.
As stated in the comments, there are specific books for that.

```
public ListNode oddEvenList(ListNode head) 
{
    //Check that there are AT LEAST TWO ELEMENTS
    if (head == null || head.next == null)
         return head;

    //Initialize pointers
    ListNode lastOdd = head;
    ListNode lastEven = head.next;
    ListNode firstEven = lastEven;

    //Continue as long as there is at least two more elements
    while (lastOdd.next != null && lastEven.next != null)
    {
            //Connect the last odd element with the element next to the
            //last even one (such element is odd)
            lastOdd.next = lastEven.next;
            //Advance lastOdd to such element
            lastOdd = lastOdd.next;

            //Do the same for the even list, only inverting the roles
            lastEven.next = lastOdd.next;
            lastEven = lastEven.next;
     }

     //Now connect the last odd element with the first even element
     //This join the two list together
     lastOdd.next = firstEven ;

     return head;
}
```

Visually

```
    //Initialize pointers
    ListNode lastOdd = head;
    ListNode lastEven = head.next;
    ListNode firstEven = lastEven;
```

[image: Pointers initialization]

**First iteration of the cycle**

```
lastOdd.next = lastEven.next;
```

[image: First iteration, I1]

```
lastOdd = lastOdd.next;
```

[image: First iteration, I2]

```
lastEven.next = lastOdd.next;
```

[image: First iteration, I3]

```
lastEven = lastEven.next;
```

[image: First iteration, I4]

**All other iterations**

As you can now imagine, the cycle repeat while **both** `lastEven` and `lastOdd` have a next element, since the former is one element ahead of the latter, this translates into having **at least two elements not processed** in the list.

[image: All remaining iterations]

Once the cycle ends, the only thing left is joining the two list

[image: Lists joined]

Comment: Well written answer. Kudos.

Answer (score 4):

Say you start with a singly-linked list. It will typically have a head and tail pointers (left and right slanted here), and each link points to the next one.

In the following diagram, the even nodes are blue, and the odd ones are grey.

[image]

One way to solve this problem would be to hold 6 pointers:

- A pointer to the link you're currently processing in the original list, and a pointer to the tail of the original list.
- A pointer to the head and tail of the even nodes you've already processed.
- A pointer to the head and tail of the odd nodes you've already processed.

(This is still *O(1)*.)

In the diagram above, the original list (what's left of it) is to the right. The processed even-nodes list is in the top left, and the processed odd-nodes list is in the bottom left.

[image]

Now, while you still have unprocessed nodes in the original list, move the current node to either the even or odd list, as necessary. At the end, just make the tail link of one point to the head node of the other. Set the head and tail pointers of the original list be this resulting list, and you're done.

Comment: what If I don't have the tail pointer ? the solution doesn't contain the tail pointer

Comment: You must have at least one pointer to know where the list begins (otherwise, it's impossible to solve). Iterate over it until the next pointer is null, and you have the other one. This doesn't alter the time complexity.

Comment: I know what a linked list is, but I couldn't solve the problem, what books do you recommend to read or what to do solve such programming problems ? can I have your skype, I need to talk with you, I need to learn from you

Comment: To learn about these things, I strongly recommend [Introduction to Algorithms](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms), which is a very good and readable book. If you need further help on topics, please ask further on this site (I'll be happy to answer too).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than writing the code, I'll just give you a very brief synopsis of the basic concept, that hopefully should be simple enough to understand. If you start to draw out various diagrams, I think you can get easily confused here. It's not necessary to draw complicated diagrams here, when the basic concepts are very simple

## Tail pointers in a singly-linked list

Let's define what a "tail pointer" is. A tail pointer is a pointer to the `nullptr` at the end of the linked list. It's a double pointer.

When the singly-linked list is empty:

```
node *head=0;
```

That, right there, is the `nullptr` in question:

```
node **tailptr= &head;
```

`tailptr` points to the end of the link list, which is, at this point, the head pointer.

## Appending using the tail pointer

What does having the tail pointer allow you to do? Well, it allows you to end a new node to the end of the list, without having to find it, starting at `head`. You already know how to add an element to the beginning of the linked list. Now, you can add one to the end, just as easy:

```
node *p=new node;

*tailptr=p;

p->next=0;
tailptr= &p->next;
```

If you keep in mind that `tailptr` points to the `nullptr` pointer at the end of the list, then this should make perfect sense. You simply change the `nullptr` to point to the new node that gets inserted at the end of the list. And the new node's `tailptr`, which is `nullptr`, since it's now the new last node, is the new tail pointer.

## Conclusion

That's all you need to know in order to implement this homework assignment.

You simply create your odd an even lists:

```
node *odd=0, *even=n0;
```

Declare their tail pointers:

```
node **tailptrs[2]={ &odd, &even};

int next_one=0;
```

Then, iterate over your original singly-linked list, appending each entry to `tailptrs[next_one]`, then flipping it: `next_one=1-next_one`. So each node, as you walk through the original list, gets appended to the odd and the even list, alternating between the two. That's even simpler than the convoluted Java-based logic you showed.

The tricky part that you need to get right is to remember that the node's original `next` is still a part of the original link list. One trick is to update each `tailptr` **without** setting the current node's `next` to `nullptr`, but wait until the original singly-linked list has been completely iterated over, and then simply set both of the final tail pointers to `nullptr` explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Idea is to keep collecting odd nodes together(in beginning) simultaneously keeping track of odd and even pointers.

```
void groupOddNode(){
    Node o,e,p,q;
    o= head;
    p= head;
    e= head.next;

    while(p.next!= null && p.next.next!= null){

        p=p.next;
        q=p.next;


        p.next = q.next;
        q.next = e;
        o.next = q;

        e=q.next;
        o=o.next;

    }

}
```

for example 
 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9

after 1st iteration:
1-3-2-4-5-6-7-8-9
(e points to 2 and 
o points to 3)

after 2nd iteration:
1-3-5-2-4-6-7-8-9
(e points to 2 and
o points to 5)

after 3rd iteration:
1-3-5-7-2-4-6-8-9
(e points to 2 and
o points to 7)

after 4th iteration:
1-3-5-7-9-2-4-6-8
(e points to 2 and
o points to 9)

i hope it help :)

Comment: this is my first answer :P

Answer (score 0):

We use two pointers, p1 and p2, to trace the odd and even nodes, respectively. If the length of the list is even, we stop at p2.next == null, i.e, when p2 reaches to the last node.

In this case, p1 is in the node next to the last. e.g.

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null

         |      |
         p1    p2
```

If the length of the list is odd, we stop at p2 == null, i.e, p1 is in the last node.

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null

                    |      |

                    p1   p2
```

We can observe that p1 is always one step below the p2, and we must let p1 stop at the last node of the odd list, then finally p1.next = evenHead. That is, we cannot lose the tail of the odd list, i.e., let p1 = null.

Solution :

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode oddEvenList(ListNode head) {
        if (head == null || head.next == null) {
            return head;
        }

        ListNode odd = head;
        ListNode even = head.next;
        ListNode evenHead = even;

        while (even != null && even.next != null) {
            odd.next = even.next;
            odd = odd.next;

            even.next = odd.next;
            even = even.next;
        }

        odd.next = evenHead;

        return head;
    }
}
```